# I'm very thin. How can I gain muscle?

Tags: weight-gain

I'm 16.5 years old and my height is 5ft 4.5inch. My weight is 45.5 kg. Everybody says that I'm very thin. How can I gain muscle and look like a healthy man? I want to create quality muscle as well.

Comment: Good news, what you need has a very easy solution. See the linked question and follow those instructions.

Comment: It is a duplicate for sure. Start by eating like a pig. But that's part of it, see full answer linked by Eric.

Comment: See my answer here, worked for me: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/im-16-120lbs-56-how-do-i-get-more-muscle-and-get-stronger-as-well/28341#28341